# Admob for Unity app does not show add

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have a problem with admob for unity app, I used documentation to add admob, I  used video tutorial from youtube and I tried demo app (hello world from admob), but the result is the same, ad banners does not appear in my apps, as for, if use interstitials, when I try to show it, my app crashes. However, in console there is a dummy message.

my code

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdMobManager : MonoBehaviour {

private BannerView bannerView;

[SerializeField] private string appID = "";
[SerializeField] private string bannerID = "";
[SerializeField] private string regularAD = "";

private void Awake(){
    MobileAds.Initialize(appID);
}

public void OnClickShowBanner() {
    this.RequestBanner();
}


public void OnClickShowAd() {
    this.RequestReqularAd();
}

private void RequestReqularAd() {
    InterstitialAd AD = new InterstitialAd(regularAD); 

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    AD.LoadAd(request);
}

public void RequestBanner() {
    bannerView = new BannerView(bannerID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code for admob banner. some time it takes time to display banner ad but this script worked fine.
[Source](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/banner)

```
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.RequestBanner();
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used it already, but I have the same problem with this code... may be I have some problems with UNITY. what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Source code available https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob/blob/master/AdmobPluginRes/admobdemo.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using admob;
public class admobdemo : MonoBehaviour {
    Admob ad;
    string appID="";
    string bannerID="";
    string interstitialID="";
    string videoID="";
    string nativeBannerID = "";

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("start unity demo-------------");
         initAdmob();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Escape)) {
            Debug.Log(KeyCode.Escape+"-----------------");
        }
    }

    void initAdmob()
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
                 appID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511";
                 bannerID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
                 interstitialID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
                 videoID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
                 nativeBannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
                 appID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
                 bannerID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
                 interstitialID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
                 videoID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
                 nativeBannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";
#endif
        AdProperties adProperties = new AdProperties();
        adProperties.isTesting = true;

        ad = Admob.Instance();
            ad.bannerEventHandler += onBannerEvent;
            ad.interstitialEventHandler += onInterstitialEvent;
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardedVideoEvent;
            ad.nativeBannerEventHandler += onNativeBannerEvent;
            ad.initSDK(appID,adProperties);//reqired,adProperties can been null
    }
    void OnGUI(){
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(120, 0, 100, 60), "showInterstitial"))
        {
           Debug.Log("touch inst button -------------");
            if (ad.isInterstitialReady())
            {
                ad.showInterstitial();
            }
            else
            {
                ad.loadInterstitial(interstitialID);
            }
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(240, 0, 100, 60), "showRewardVideo"))
        {
            Debug.Log("touch video button -------------");
            if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady())
            {
                ad.showRewardedVideo();
            }
            else
            {
                ad.loadRewardedVideo(videoID);
            }
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 100, 100, 60), "showbanner"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(bannerID,AdSize.SMART_BANNER, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(120, 100, 100, 60), "showbannerABS"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().showBannerAbsolute(bannerID,AdSize.BANNER, 20, 220,"mybanner");
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(240, 100, 100, 60), "removebanner"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().removeBanner();
            Admob.Instance().removeBanner("mybanner");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 200, 100, 60), "showNative"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().showNativeBannerRelative(nativeBannerID,new AdSize(320,280), AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(120, 200, 100, 60), "showNativeABS"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().showNativeBannerAbsolute(nativeBannerID,new AdSize(-1,132), 0, 300);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(240, 200, 100, 60), "removeNative"))
        {
            Admob.Instance().removeNativeBanner();
        }
    }
    void onInterstitialEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
        if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdLoaded)
        {
            Admob.Instance().showInterstitial();
        }
    }
    void onBannerEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobBannerEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }
    void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "  rewarded: " + msg);
    }
    void onNativeBannerEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobNativeBannerEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }
}
```